# map static website to new URL but use the same files?

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

I have a static website, say it's URL is:

```
http://website.com
```

And its files paths:

```
/path/to/website/
```

I want to serve the same files/folders from this directory into a new directory and add just a css file to the end of its files `<head>`;

So, in order to show it on new styles I want its URLs to be like this:

```
http://website.com/new-style/1/
http://website.com/new-style/2/
http://website.com/new-style/3/
....
```

And its html/css/js files to be served from the original directory:

```
/path/to/website/
+
/path/to/website/new-style/1/style.css
                 ^--------------------
/path/to/website/new-style/2/style.css
/path/to/website/new-style/3/style.css
```

How can I do that?

Is it needed to be server-side rewrite or something?

I can use PHP and Apache as a web-server.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean you want to serve the same files/folders from the directory to a new directory?

Comment: I mean that I don't want copy/paste the HTML files into a new directory, I want to use it once everywhere, because I may edit them later. So, I don't want to edit them again!

Comment: Oh, I think I understood. You want to see the same static website in 3 different styles (using css) for each of the 3 URL. You say static but if you use apache it means you are using php right?

Comment: OK do they have to be HTML files? If you put a line of PHP in the `<head>` and use `mod_rewrite` it's an easy fix....

Comment: It's already HTML files. My main concern is using the `.html` extension at the end of the files! in order to keep the SEO, you know

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP files instead of HTML

```
//index.php
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style<?php print $_GET['style'];?>">
...
</head>
<body>
...
```

And then in you .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/website/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^new-style/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ /$2\.php?style=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The last line renames the html extensions into PHP

EDIT (because it might not be very clear): The last line does not really *rename* the html pages in the address, it just *interprets* them as PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony!

Comment: But if I used `.php` extensions I'll need to rewrite them to `.html` , not the opposite!

Comment: What do you mean? You use `.php` so that that 1 line of code works and then use the `.htaccess` file to "pretend" they are `.html` files.

Comment: I sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you... So, what the URLs would be?

Comment: www.yourwebsite.com/index.html ---TRANSLATED TO--> www.yourwebsite.com/index.php

The user writes index.html and your server reads index.php

Comment: It's a way of masking the fact that they are php files... Although I am pretty sure you are going through a lot of trouble for nothing... I am not sure HTML is better for SEO than PHP....